# How do I fix "AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'news'" in Pycord?

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror, pycord

I have recently started using [Pycord](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/) to make a Discord bot. However, I have quickly run into an error that I'm not sure how to deal with.

**Here is my code:**

```py
import discord

bot = discord.Bot(debug_guilds=[<my guild ID>])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    print(message)

bot.run('token')
```

**Here is the error:**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\DiscordBot\env\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 382, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Username/Desktop/DiscordBot/main.py", line 18, in on_message
    print(message)
  File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\DiscordBot\env\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 777, in __repr__
    return f"<{name} id={self.id} channel={self.channel!r} type={self.type!r} author={self.author!r} flags={self.flags!r}>"
  File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\DiscordBot\env\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 190, in __repr__
    attrs = [(val, getattr(self, val)) for val in self._repr_attrs]
  File "c:\Users\Username\Desktop\DiscordBot\env\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 190, in <listcomp>
    attrs = [(val, getattr(self, val)) for val in self._repr_attrs]
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'news'
```

I'm not sure why this error occurs because, to my knowledge, the [`TextChannel`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel) object does not have the attribute "`news`". The closest thing I could find is [`is_news()`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.is_news).

**Checklist:**

Checked for duplicate questions.
Checked [Pycord API reference](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html) for [`on_message`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message).
Attempted to print just the message [`content`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.content) instead of the [`message`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Message) object.
Checked intent issues by confirming that `Message Intent` is enabled on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

**Environment Information:**

OS: Windows 7
Python Version: 3.8.10 (Stuck on this version because Python 3.9 and up no longer supports Windows 7)
Python Virtual Environment Name: env
Pycord Version: 2.0.0rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should upgrade your pycord to development version.

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```

It seems that in this [commit](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/commit/2e580d2a1d41c3ff22d8c97a01f363d5808b60a6), they've added the `news` attribute.

Comment: I have used "pip install -U py-cord --pre" to install Pycord. Is that not the development version?

Comment: @SirFire The last pre-release version on pypi is from 4 days ago. The commit that added the `news` attribute was made less than a day ago.

Comment: I ran "pip install -U git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord" and it seems to have changed nothing. Do I have to first uninstall the existing Pycord and reinstall it from the GitHub link?

Comment: @SirFire Yeah, sure. Try it.